# Find a number of characters/letters in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find a number of "a" characters in a string. Ideally, I want to get an output as an array that would print out in the console something like: c - 15, b - 5, a - 4 etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function findStrings() {
mainString="Mazher Mahmood is a clever, canny and creative reporter who generates his own  stories. It's important to place that on record because, before we delve into his use of the darker journalistic arts, there should not be any illusion about his reporting skills. "

result=(mainString.split("a").length - 1);

console.log(result);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to count the number of occurrences of all letters?

Comment: Do you need to also count spaces, dots, commas? Do you need a case sensitive count?

Comment: Thank you for so many replies! Fabrizio, ideally, yes.  I want basically create a stats table of how many of different SAME characters occur in a string. A=a would do too, i.e. not case sensitive. Commas, spaces and dots would be good to know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to loop through each letter, making the check as you go and perhaps append it to an object:

```
function findStrings() {
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        ret = {};
    for(i=0; i<letters.length; i++){    
        ret[letters[i]]=(mainString.split(letters[i]).length - 1);
    }
    console.log(ret);
}

findStrings();
```

Should you want to explicitly check for any other characters, just add them on to the end of the `letters` string.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDhDB/)

Comment: @user2890981 Glad to have helped.

Comment: Can I ask a stupid question? You have this piece of code ret[letters[i]]=(mainString.split(letters[i]).length - 1) + (mainString.split(letters[i].toUpperCase()).length - 1). In this case ret[letters[i]] is simply a matrix? And this matrix has a default syntax in js? Because I don't quite understand how you print out an object {a: n1, b: n2, c: n3 etc.}

Comment: `letters[i]` is the current letter in the loop. So `ret[letters[i]]` would be expressed as `ret['a']` which is the same as `ret.a`. The number of occurences (the part you provided) is assigned to `ret[current letter]`

Comment: Super understandable! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the occurrences of letters/characters, you just have to loop through the string:

```
function findStrings() {    
    var mainString="Mazher Mahmood is a clever, canny and creative reporter who generates his own  stories. It's important to place that on record because, before we delve into his use of the darker journalistic arts, there should not be any illusion about his reporting skills. "

    var findings = {};
    for(var i=0; i<mainString.length; i++){
        if(typeof( findings[mainString[i]] ) == "undefined"){
            findings[mainString[i]] = 0;
        }
        findings[mainString[i]]++;
    }

    for(var sym in findings){
        console.log("The character "+sym+" has been found "+findings[sym]+" times");
    }
}

findStrings();
```

**Note:** 
oGeez`s answer only counts the occurrence of specific characters, while my answer counts the occurrence of all appearing characters. Your question isn't clear enough on what you actually want to achieve.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4WWN/

Comment: Maja, it is exactly what I am trying to achieve. But the code doesn't print anything out..

Comment: @AlexZheda it works for me. You need to call `findStrings();` in order to execute the function.

Comment: Thank you Maja! It's a really nice trick with the alert message. Unfortunately, I can't rate 2 answers at once :(

Answer (score 0):

You can count like this:

```
mainString="Your Big String";

function count(str) {
  var chars = {};
  var astr = str.split("");

  for (var i = 0, len = astr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var letter = astr[i];
    chars[letter] = chars.hasOwnProperty(letter) && chars[letter] + 1 || 1;
  }
  return chars;
}

console.log(count(mainString));
```

Note that, this way, you will count the occurrence of every character, including spaces, commas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getCharAppearences(str) {
    var character,result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        character = str.charAt(i);
        result[character] = result[character] + 1 || 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/xc7PT/3/)

Comment: char is a reserved keyword and shouldn't be used as an variable-name

Comment: Oops! Didn't had that in mind. I changed it. Thanks!